# defer updates: change in policy files of Windows 10 Version 1607

Tags: group-policy, windows-update, windows-10

I am noticing that in the recently published *Windows 10 version 1607* ADMX templates the WindowsUpdate.admx brings considerable changes to the Deferred Update / Deferred Upgrade policy options.

The "Defer Upgrade" policy seems to be replaced by the "Defer Update" category and the reg values set by the policies set in the new category are different from what has been set by the "Defer Upgrade" policy.

- is there an official Microsoft reference somewhere explaining the change?
- can I use both policies / methods interchangeably for both, 1511 and 1607 versions of Windows 10 or would I need to use the old method for 1511 hosts and the new one for 1607?

Answer (score 2):

- 1507 added the simple defer upgrade setting.
- 1511 added the defer upgrade&update.
- 1607 add new policy completely.

When you upgrade a Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 the old settings migrates to the news one and the old settings are removed from the available ADMX.

At the time I wrote that answer you have to write or make manual ADMX if you want to manage older build vs newer build.

- For your point #1. I just found out that [page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1607?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#windows-updates), but it dont list the settings.
- For your point #2. 1607 will respect 1511's settings, but 1607 policy are not usable on 1511. At some point you might want to deploy the new ADMX settings for those computers.

Comment: I see. We have a domain with some dozens OU admins which might or might not have set the settings in any of their numerous policies. We have copied the new 1607 ADMX into `SYSVOL\Domain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions`. What I don't quite get: now that everybody has the "Defer Upgrade" policy setting removed, how are administrators supposed to change or un-define the old-style policy settings?

Comment: @the-wabbit You have 2 options, use https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2917033 and setup a station (1511) to create/manage those settings. or hack the central ADMX file WindowsUpdate.admx/adml files from the central store to re-add those settings. MS screwed up on that one IMO, but it's another debate

Comment: Option 1 seems not to work out as easily as PolicyDefinitions in SYSVOL seem to override the local station definitions. But thank you nonetheless.